# Free Memory after ImageBrush was set to null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, imagebrush

In my app(music player) i have feature called "Game Mode" which stops every background operations except playing music and i wanna free some memory too.

E.g. 
I have Background Image on Base Grid in my window which i set that way

```
BaseGrid.Background = new ImageBrush("the image");
```

In GameMode method i do something like this

```
BaseGrid.Background = null;
GC.Collect();
```

but it didnt free any memory when first time called, when i call the method second time it works, or if i paste the MessageBox.Show method between nulling and GC.Collect it works too.

So my question is.
Is setting Background to null Asynchronous operation that takes some time and GC.Collect didnt see unused object when its called so early after nulling or what another problem it can be?

Comment: OK according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888280/garbage-collection-does-not-reduce-current-memory-usage-in-release-mode-why) its not possible to collect at a specific point in time. Thanks for replies :)

Answer (score 0):

When ever you call

```
    GC.Collect();
```

you should call

```
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer()
```

also

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer();
```